# Bypass proxy when HTTPGET https://localhost/

Tags: http, asp.net-core, console, service-worker, http-get

I have a asp.net core 3.1 webserver that I run from Visual studio 2019 (Ctrl+F5). That has an HTTP GET endpoint which I can successfully call using REST Client in VS Code:

```
GET https://localhost:5001/api/myResource
```

Then I am trying to develop a service worker (also .net core 3.1) that I run from a console and that call's the same resource.
Like so..

```
httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseHTTP = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/myResource");
```

The response that I then get is an error message from my company's proxy (stating forbidden access bla bla bla) and what address actually was posted (part of the response content):

> While trying to retrieve the URL:
> localhost.mycompany.com:5001

Hence it has added

> mycompany.com

to the address that I supplied in the `httpClient.GetAsync()`

I have tried disabling the proxy in windows setup (incl. removing environment variables) and restarted both the console and the local webserver. But still it goes through the proxy (or I get the same forbidden answer from the proxy). Is there a way to *bypass* the proxy? All the questions and answers I have looked at is about the opposite, getting the httpClient to use the proxy.

Comment: All right I will have to make a separate mockup project (too much other stuff going on). I'll get back @Caius Jard

Comment: Get it working in Postman, then you can copy the setup

Comment: Postman wont work on my computer....

Comment: Are you literally connecting to `localhost`, or to your machine name?

Comment: @CodeCaster .. literally `localhost` (as in `await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/api/myResource");`)

Comment: It's not the only thing that can be used to send HTTP requests! Google for "postman alternative"

Comment: Oh, just noticed that you're saying your company proxy is issuing the refusal, which means your computer is erroneously submitting the request to the proxy. Locahost obviously means something different to the proxy (it means the proxy) than it mans to your computer. If your proxy setup ignores 127.0.0.1 you can try that, or you may need to use the IP address (10.x.x.x .. etc) of your own machine if everything always goes via the proxy; the proxy will then contact your IP

Comment: Give a go at setting your HttpClient up like: `var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseProxy = false }; httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);`

Comment: Also not sure why your top code says `httpClient` and your bottom code says `_httpClient` - different clients?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks a lot I will try it out. (the _httpClient was what I used in the production code and httpClient in the test example sorry for the confusion (should be corrected now....)

Comment: @CaiusJard -  the `HttpClientHandler` worked.. do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look to use something like this to disable use of the system proxy, if your `HttpClient` is picking it up from the system settings:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseProxy = false }; 
httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```